# How much wind does it take to tip a sign over?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, torque, aerodynamics

Or said another way - how much counterweight does the base of a sign need to keep it from tipping over given a specific max wind?

- Assume the sign does not let wind through
- Assume the base of the sign cannot slide on the ground
- Assume the sign does not flex in the wind
- Assume total weight of the sign + base is 125 lbs (base is 96 lbs)

Are there any other parameters needed?

The sign has the design and measurements below:
[image]

Edit: This would probably be helpful: Width of sign is 8' so the sign is 9' high x 8' wide.

Comment: By how much wind, do you mean the wind speed required to tip the sign? Also, this problem is not solvable without knowing the drag force the wind exerts on the sign

Comment: Thanks, Pranav. By drag force, is this the same as saying how much wind goes through the sign? Sorry - I'm not up on all the physics terms. Physics class was many decades ago, and I'm just an adult trying to design a marching band prop! :-) In this case, one can assume the sign is completely flat and does not let any wind through it (it's a tarp material).

Comment: Oh, and yes, by how much wind, I'm looking for how much wind the sign can take before tipping over.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to calculate where the centroid of the sign is, so assume mass is evenly distributed in base and up the height of the sign.
- You need to assume aerodynamic force is evenly distributed up the height of the sign.
- You need to assume a drag coefficient for a flat plate
- You probably want to assume it is quasi static so it will fall when the aerodynamic force is enough to pivot the sign about the edge of the base.

Free body diagram time!